# Access to 10K Privileges at 9,995 Rep?

Tags: bug

I'm almost at 10,000 reputation, but I got a notification indicating that I've been given ["access to moderator tools"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), which includes the ability to view deleted questions (which is for 10,000 or more rep).

I take it this is a (small) bug?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible at all that a user upvoted one of your posts and then unupvoted it pretty quickly? That could cause this. You're not able to access [mod tools](http://stackoverflow.com/tools) now are you?

Comment: @bluet: Good point. I hadn't considered that.

Comment: SO hysteresis causes hysterics.

Comment: is your rep 9995 on meta and 10 000 on stack maybe? there is some delay in how rep is shown in meta compared to stack

Comment: @Patrice: Nope, still 9,995 on SO (as of this writing).

Comment: @JackManey yeah right after typing it I checked it out, and you're right. But I think bluet's theory is the right one, because if I look at your meta stack profile, I see your stack overflow profile at 10010. I think someone upvoted you, canceled his upvote, and the system checked at the exact second you had 10000+ (or most likely an accepted answer, since it's a 15 points diff)

Comment: [checks again] Huh...now it's showing as 10,010 on my profile. When I created this question, it wasn't. Welp, that solves that mystery.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks. I tried searching Meta SO before asking, but couldn't find a question covering this topic.

Comment: [Should I blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had it, but then you lost it.

Someone's unupvote, either through a question or an answer, has caused you to lose the privilege which you previously earned.

So long as you don't actually have access to any of the moderator panels or can see deleted questions, I'd say that this is by design.